# Unmask datetime - inputmask

Tags: javascript, input-mask

Using [Inputmask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inputmask) vanilla js version.

Having problems with unmasking datetime format:

```
var expDate = document.getElementById('expDate');

Inputmask({
    alias: 'datetime',
    inputFormat: 'mm/yy',
    placeholder: 'month/year',
    autoUnmask: true,
    clearMaskOnLostFocus: false
}).mask(expDate);
```

`autoUnmask` not working, `expDate.value` returns `12/12`, though it should be returning `1212`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`outputFormat: ddmm` does what i needed, but it's not mentioned in documentation of this plugin.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a minimal example and the **autoUnmask** option is working, maybe there are some conflicts with **alias: 'datetime'** or **inputFormat: 'mm/yy'**. Read next documentation that is available on the plugin web site:

**aliases**

With an alias you can define a complex mask definition and call it by using an alias name. So this is mainly to simplify the use of your masks. Some aliases found in the extensions are: email, currency, decimal, integer, date, datetime, dd/mm/yyyy, etc.

First you have to create an alias definition. The alias definition can contain options for the mask, custom definitions, the mask to use etc.

When you pass in an alias, the alias is first resolved and then the other options are applied. So you can call an alias and pass another mask to be applied over the alias. This also means that you can write aliases which "inherit" from another alias.

Some examples can be found in jquery.inputmask.xxx.extensions.js

**format**

Instead of masking an input element it is also possible to use the inputmask for formatting given values. Think of formatting values to show in jqGrid or on other elements then inputs.

var formattedDate = Inputmask.format("2331973", { alias: "datetime", inputFormat: "dd/mm/yyyy"});

Like you can see, **datetime** is a defined alias (you can check the definition on *inputmask.date.extensions.js*), and inputFormat is used for other purposes. On the next example, there is one input with **autoUnmask** option configured on **true** and the other with the default value of **false**:

```js
// Get the inputs fields

var expDate1 = document.getElementById('expDate1');
var expDate2 = document.getElementById('expDate2');

// Apply masks on the inputs.

Inputmask({
    alias: 'date',
    autoUnmask: true,
    clearMaskOnLostFocus: false
}).mask(expDate1);

Inputmask({
    alias: 'date',
    clearMaskOnLostFocus: false
}).mask(expDate2);

// Alert values.

function getValuesFromInputs()
{
    var msg = "Value of Input1 with autoUnmask=true: " + expDate1.value;
    msg += "\n"
    msg += "Value of Input2 with autoUnmask=false: " + expDate2.value;

    alert(msg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/dependencyLibs/inputmask.dependencyLib.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/inputmask/inputmask.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/inputmask/inputmask.extensions.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/inputmask/inputmask.date.extensions.js"></script>

<input type="input" id="expDate1"/>
<input type="input" id="expDate2"/>
<button type="button" onclick="getValuesFromInputs()">Get Values</button>
```